# How to retrieve number using regex and preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to retrieve the ten digit id number from a textarea.

```
e.g id no 1234567890
```

I was trying to use.

```
preg_match("/('/^[0-9]{10}/')/", $article, $tags);
```

But it does not work. I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match_all("/\d{10}/", $article, $tags);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{10}/', $article, $tags);
```

Try that.  Or if you have multiple IDs, you can use `preg_match_all`.

```
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{10}/', $article, $tags);
```

Comment: Or with preg_match_all, for multi-results